# Удаляются файлы после загрузки по ftp

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ftp

немогу понять, почему то после загрузки файлов на сервер по фтп, они сразу же удаляются, а папки остаются.Загружают от пользователя не от рута. В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: а какие команды вы при этом используете? Ну и класика - возможно ваш юзер не обладает нужными привилегиями для данных действий.

Comment: @alexoander я просто по фтп загружаю. Некоторые файлы остаются, некоторые удаляются. Сейчас вроде загрузил, но пришлось добавить в архив, загружать архив, а потом извлечь его))

Comment: *я просто по фтп загружаю* — спрашивали вас не про протокол (его вы написали уже в вопросе), а про команды, которыми загружаете. // а вообще вам следует адресовать вопрос администратору ftp-сервера (если это не вы сами).